# CentOS 7 fresh installation having trouble sending emails to gmail

Tags: centos, postfix, centos7, sendmail, gmail

I have just setup a small VPS on Vultr.com using CentOS 7 to serve a few Wordpress sites.

Apart from Nginx and PHP the server is completely fresh.

The Wordpress setup went fine except when trying to send emails it doesn't go through.

I have checked the /var/log/maillog and it is full with errors like so;

```
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19866]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.191.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19867]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.191.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19868]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.168.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19869]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.191.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19870]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.168.26]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19871]: connect to alt2.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.191.27]:25: Connection timed out
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19871]: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4003:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19868]: 8BDEC6DA3: to=<admin@website.com>, relay=none, delay=55132, delays=55072/0.03/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.168.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19870]: 034A76DAB: to=<admin@website.com>, relay=none, delay=1549, delays=1489/0.05/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[64.233.168.26]:25: Connection timed out)
Jan  8 18:29:56 myhostname postfix/smtp[19871]: 083EB6DA9: to=<admin@website.com>, relay=none, delay=26662, delays=26602/0.06/60/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4003:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
Jan  8 18:29:57 myhostname postfix/pickup[19864]: 918676DB7: uid=997 from=<nginx>
Jan  8 18:29:57 myhostname postfix/cleanup[19885]: 918676DB7: message-id=<af31451917cf0462f5d0ff4d6657d8bd@website.com>
Jan  8 18:29:57 myhostname postfix/qmgr[3434]: 918676DB7: from=<nginx@myhostname.website.com>, size=781, nrcpt=1 (queue active)
Jan  8 18:29:57 myhostname postfix/error[19886]: 918676DB7: to=<admin@website.com>, relay=none, delay=0.07, delays=0.06/0.01/0/0, dsn=4.4.1, status=deferred (delivery temporarily suspended: connect to alt1.aspmx.l.google.com[2607:f8b0:4003:c07::1a]:25: Network is unreachable)
```

Also, when running the following, no emails are coming through;

```
echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v email@mydomain.com.au
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated in getting this going.

Comment: What happens if you send to other email providers than gmail?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure it isn't blocked by selinux (`/var/log/audit/audit.log`). Usually you have to specifically allow webservers to send emails when selinux is enabled (`setsebool -P httpd_can_sendmail`).

If this is not the case, outgoing connections on port 25 are blocked by a firewall. In that case contact your hoster. Either they provide you with an SMTP server you can use, or they can open the port in their firewall.

Since the `sendmail` command doesn't work either, I suspect it's the latter case.

Comment: Hey thanks for that ... I just tried firewall-cmd --permanent --add-service=smtp and still nothing ... Is this different to the firewall you are talking about?

Comment: I'm talking about the firewall of your hoster. The firewall on a server usually only concerns incoming connections. Blocking port 25 is common with cheap hosters to prevent abuse of their infrastructure by spammers.

Comment: Ohhhh ok, that makes sense .. Thank you, i shall contact them

Answer (score 1):

It looks like vultr.com is blocking outside connections to port 25 and you should contact them to unblock it.

Read this: https://www.vultr.com/faq/#outboundsmtp (I've found this in this discussion https://discuss.vultr.com/discussion/1027/smtp-port-25-is-supposed-to-have-been-opened-but-doesnt-seem-to).

You could also check if port is really blocked by issuing for example this command `nmap -p 25 64.233.191.27 -Pn` (you have to install nmap at first if you already didn't).

Comment: Hey, thanks for that, when i run the nmap command, i get the following 25/tcp filtered smtp